# Knots into 2D surfaces

Tags: general-topology, knot-theory

I know that every compact 2D surface can be thought of as a sphere with a certain number of handles and Möbius strips attached. Given a knot diagram, is it trivial to understand what 2D surface one obtains by replacing the "wire" (BTW, what's the math jargon for the lace?) with a tube? My guess is that we shall always obtain different embedings of a usual torus into 3D. If so, are there more interesting ways to obtain 2D surfaces from knots by more interesting mappings?

Comment: Maybe this can interest you: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seifert_surface

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your construction (do you take a knot, thicken it into a solid torus, then take its boundary?), but with this parenthetical assumption, here's a converse: every embedded torus in $S^3$ (i.e., the $3$-sphere, the one-point compactification of Euclidean 3D space) is isotopic to the tube of some knot.  Another fact is that only orientable closed surfaces can be embedded in 3D.